# SOQL Query On Junction Object Not Return Data For Site Guest User

Tags: apex, soql, force.com-sites

I have created a junction object called 'Test1__c' between Opportunity and Contact, soql query on Test1__c object return nothing and got below error.
"System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject".
I have given read permissions to the Opportunity, Contact and Test1__C object on the Profile of the site guest user but the problem still persists. Also mark apex class as a 'Without Sharing'.
On sharing setting module please the see the below setting:
[image: Sharing Setting]

I did all the possible ways that need to resolve this problem but no use.
Please help me to resolve this issue, I would be so thankful!

Comment: If you run the query in the developer console or through an anonymous apex script, does it return record? Could you show the code that contains the query?

Comment: In developer console it returns the record, sorry rael_kid I can not share the code and thanks for the response.

Comment: @rael_kid, If removed Applicant__c=:contactId then it  returns data.WHERE 
                                                   Is_Current_Employer__c = true and 
                                                   Applicant__r.Applicant_Type__c = 'Primary Applicant' 
                                                   AND Applicant__c =:contactId LIMIT 1